Android: Action bar back button leaves the app unresponsive after being tap
Even when I've just realised that action bar back button is not completely necessary in my app (because access to all screens are already present in footer menu), I need to understand why it is making my app unresponsive.
To start with necessary information, I'll first say that my main activity is "TestTypeMenuActivity" and that all activities inherit from a base activity called "BaseActivity".
Let's take one of my activities as an example to work with, CollegeSearchActivity:
In my AndroidManifest I define it and set its parent to main activity as follows:
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.main.collegesearch.CollegeSearchActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".ui.activities.test.testtypemenu.TestTypeMenuActivity" />
</activity>

In CollegeSearchActivity:
override fun createActionBar() {
    val activityTitle = TMLocale.getStringResourceByResId(R.string.activitycommunity_textview_findcolleges).uppercase()
    super.createActionBar(activityTitle, showBackButton = true, capitalizeTitle = true)
}

In BaseActivity:
fun createActionBar(title: String, showBackButton: Boolean, capitalizeTitle: Boolean){
    if(useToolBar){
        val toolbar = this.createToolbar(title, capitalizeTitle)
        if (toolbar!=null) setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(showBackButton)
        val toolbarColor = getActivityTextColor()
        toolbar?.setNavigationIconColor(Color.parseColor(toolbarColor))
    }
}

Extension Methods class:
fun Activity.createToolbar(actionbarTitle: String, capitalizeTitle: Boolean = true): Toolbar? {
    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    if (toolbar != null) {
        this.setActionBarBackground(toolbar)
        val capitalizedTitle = if (capitalizeTitle)
            WordUtils.capitalizeFully(actionbarTitle) else actionbarTitle
        val tvActionBarTitle = toolbar.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvActionBarTitle)

        val textColor = BaseActivity.getAppTextColor(context)
        tvActionBarTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor))

        if (tvActionBarTitle != null) tvActionBarTitle.text = capitalizedTitle
    }

    return toolbar
}

Everything was working fine until now, when suddenly back button in action bar started making my app unresponsive, and I cannot figure out why.
The weird thing is that if I insert the next lines -taken from here: App crashes when I press the Up(back) button in settings menu- into my BaseActivity the problem just disappears:
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        super.onBackPressed()
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

Instead of being "lazy" and just forget about the issue when it is solved just putting that lines below, I need to understand why the problem started happening (and why that lines solves it) when that was not needed until now.
Any help?
Edit 1: Adding logcat output.
Having cleared the logcat after any screen accessed, after I hit back button this is the logcat output.
2024-04-29 19:49:39.261  2431-4576  ThermalTraceService     com.huawei.iaware                    I  code:1, appInfo:com.xxx.xxx#10000, levelInfo:0,warm_system_h,7
2024-04-29 19:49:39.527  4864-4864  Settings                com...xxx.xxx  W  Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
2024-04-29 19:49:39.528  4864-4864  HiTouch_HiTouchSensor   com...xxx.xxx  V  User setup is finished.
2024-04-29 19:49:39.740  4864-4864  AudioManager            com...xxx.xxx  V  querySoundEffectsEnabled...
2024-04-29 19:49:43.090  4864-4929  ZrHungImpl              com...xxx.xxx  I  sendRawEvent. wpId = 257
2024-04-29 19:49:43.092  4864-4929  HiView.HiEvent          com...xxx.xxx  E  length is 0 or exceed MAX: 1024
2024-04-29 19:49:45.405  4864-4929  ZrHungImpl              com...xxx.xxx  I  sendRawEvent. wpId = 258
2024-04-29 19:49:45.405  4864-4929  HiView.HiEvent          com...xxx.xxx  E  length is 0 or exceed MAX: 1024
2024-04-29 19:49:47.537  4864-4885  lsatactexampre          com...xxx.xxx  I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 109772(6560KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 8312KB/16MB, paused 150us total 103.835ms
2024-04-29 19:49:54.273  2431-4576  ThermalTraceService     com.huawei.iaware                    I  code:1, appInfo:com.xxx.xxx#10000, levelInfo:0,warm_system_h,6#0,warm_systemh_screenoff,1
2024-04-29 19:49:56.395  4864-4885  lsatactexampre          com...xxx.xxx  I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 111727(6869KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 10034KB/19MB, paused 122us total 112.971ms
2024-04-29 19:50:09.785  4864-4885  lsatactexampre          com...xxx.xxx  I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 132123(7836KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 12MB/24MB, paused 215us total 124.915ms
2024-04-29 19:50:19.288  2431-4576  ThermalTraceService     com.huawei.iaware                    I  code:1, appInfo:com.xxx.xxx#10000, levelInfo:0,warm_system_h,5


can you post what's happening in the logs.
